# Should I list a position on my resume that has little to do with the field I'm entering?

Tags: resume

I'm getting my degree in computer science and want a job in software development. In addition, I enjoy creating electronic music as my hobby. As a result, I work part-time (about 5-20 hours a month) with a local video game company, producing the soundtrack for their game in my spare time.

I have enough internship and research experience to fill out my resume without listing this other position. I'm wondering whether or not I should include it in my resume. On one hand, it is a professional, skilled position I hold and shows that I have a diverse skill set and work hard. In addition, it might be dishonest not to discuss it. On the other hand, it doesn't show that I'd make a better software developer and might suggest that I'd rather work on these side projects than give my best to companies I apply to.

Should I include positions, like this music position, that don't relate directly to the field I'm entering on my resume? Does it matter much one way or the other?

Comment: *In addition, it might be dishonest not to discuss it.* - If you're in the US, then don't worry about this. Tailoring your resume for the position you're applying for is expected. (If you're filling out an application asking for all your work experience then you should list all positions.) That said, I agree with user2989297 in your particular case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would include it. Diversity and adaptability as an employee are highly valuable and sought after characteristics.

While you're right that depending on the recruiter, it could backfire and make it appear as if you wouldn't dedicate 110% to this position, odds are it will actually come across as motivation and competence.

I mean, the primary focus of my work experience is QA, but having retail, telesales, and academic research experience on my resume has always been received well for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think if the relevant parts of the resume are already long/detailed (which seems like it is the case), you should leave off jobs that are not relevant.

Depending on the size and structure of the company you are applying to, they may be looking at tons of resumes. You want to make it as easy as possible for the person reading the resume to see the *relevant* work, so they will know why you are a good fit. If you do include your current position, definitely list your relevant experience first, even if its not chronological. Also, nothing wrong with having a list of hobbies or special interests at the end of your resume.

If I see a resume with work experience completely unrelated to the job I posted, it makes me wonder why the candidate would even want this job and if they'd be happy with the work, since their current work is so different. It all depends on who is making the decisions (and how clear your cover letter is).

Another thought: your resume could include a link to your LinkedIn or AboutMe page, where the full details of all your work experience could be listed.

Answer (score 3):

I think one big thing the answerers here forgot is that the OP is a recent college grad. It would be expected that such a person would have limited relevant job(s) in the field they are applying. The only negative thing going for the OP is that the job market today is looking for people with experience and recent college grads are having trouble securing a entry level job.

Personally I think you should show the music gig that you did. You worked in videogames which in itself is related to computer science and as such, I think such a position is relevant.